# Generate update or replace statements from database diff

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-migration

I have two dumps of a mysql database sharing the same schema.
I would like to generate a sql script to update b to the state of a.

- When having different inserts on the same primary key, I would like to generate an update statement.
- For rows only in b, I would like to generate deletes.
- For rows only in a, I would like to generate inserts.

Is there a better way than scripting this based on text processors like awk or sed?

Comment: As currently written, this question is off-topic for Stackoverflow (seeking recommendations). You should consider editing it to be a "How can I" question (without reference to external tools).

Comment: Import the second database into a different database name. Then using cross database reference conduct your update/delete/insert statements.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, @Nick. I have updated the question accordingly